# How can I avoid fields being disabled on AJAX requests (attribute disabled) in Drupal?

Tags: forms, ajax, 9

I want to make an input not be disabled when I submit an ajax request.
I tried reversed variants in [these answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14450/disable-all-form-elements-when-doing-ajax), i.e. hanging an "AjaxStart" on the document.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $('#edit-search-request').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

And tried to reassign `beforeSubmit` method:

```
drupalSettings.ajax['edit-search-request'].beforeSubmit = beforeSubmit;

function beforeSubmit (form_values, form, options) {
  #('#edit-search-request').attr('disabled', false).removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

They both fires up but the input still gets disabled during an AJAX request.

Why am I doing this: I got an input with auto-suggestions but on mobiles when the ajax request been sent - the input gets disabled and the keyboard on the phone hides as well. Then it pop-ups again. This is not good for UX. Maybe there is a better solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: I can't understand exactly what you're explaining or asking. Can you be more specific as to the situation, and also more specific as to what specifically you want to happen instead?

Comment: @Jaypan because you don't understand something it deserves downvotes?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think I would know why someone else downvoted you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution

```
        // Disable [disabled] attribute on the input.
        const defaultBeforeSend = Drupal.Ajax.prototype.beforeSend;
        Drupal.Ajax.prototype.beforeSend = amendBeforeSubmit;

        function amendBeforeSubmit (xmlhttprequest, options) {

          defaultBeforeSend(xmlhttprequest, options);
          $('#edit-search-request').prop('disabled', false);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of @mevsme broke our JS. I now use this example based on facets-views-ajax.js.

```js
  var beforeSend = Drupal.Ajax.prototype.beforeSend;

  Drupal.Ajax.prototype.beforeSend = function (xmlhttprequest, options)
  {
    // Call the original Drupal method with the right context.
    beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
    $('#edit-search-request').prop('disabled', false);
  }
```